# Fixing table cells for horizontal scrolling

Tags: css

I'm trying to fix the first and last column (.headcol, .lastcol) in a horizontally scrolling table so they always appear flush to the left & right of the visible panel.

It was my understanding that `position: absolute` elements would be relative to the first parent that has `position: relative`. However, they insist on positioning themselves relative to the scrollable element (one div up).

Try scrolling right in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/benkeen/hav6eLst/

I'd like the white first col and the red last column to stay in place and only the yellow content get scrolled.

Here's the code.

```css
#top {
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

#pos-relative {
  position: relative;
}

table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

td,
th {
  margin: 0;
  border: 3px solid grey;
  border-top-width: 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.headcol {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  left: 0;
  border-right: 0px none black;
  border-top-width: 3px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  background-color: white;
}

.headcol:before {
  content: 'Row ';
}

.lastcol {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.long {
  background: yellow;
  letter-spacing: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">
  <div id="pos-relative">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">1</th>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <th class="lastcol">x</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">2</th>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <th class="lastcol">x</th>
      </tr>
      ... more rows
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Am I barking up the wrong tree here? Perhaps this isn't doable with tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies for the confusion everyone. Yes, this was perfectly do-able - I just needed to invert the two top-level elements, so the scrollable element via was within the position: relative element, therefore fixing the white + red cells horizontally, but still allowing normal vertical scrolling.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/benkeen/4z0x297L/2/

```css
#pos-relative {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}


#top {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

td,
th {
  margin: 0;
  border: 3px solid grey;
  border-top-width: 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.headcol {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  left: 0;
  border-right: 0px none black;
  border-top-width: 3px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  background-color: white;
}

.headcol:before {
  content: 'Row ';
}

.lastcol {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.long {
  background: yellow;
  letter-spacing: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="pos-relative">
  <div id="top">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th class="headcol">1</th>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td>
        <th class="lastcol">x</th>
      </tr>
      ... more rows 
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup, took a lot of bashing my head against the wall, but got there in the end. Thanks very much for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand in the right way you want to make first col fix and other scrollable  (h or v ) if this is wright this is the js work you should put some java script to work like what you want there is a ton of example in the web just google it    ^_^

Comment: This is not an answer, please try to comment instead.

Comment: Thank you for your comment i'm new in stack over flow community thanx again ^_^,i will not do this mistake again